# can any one explain how to get distinct records from a table.?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I get distinct records from a table?

Someone suggested this query to me:

```
select * from emp a 
where rowid = (select max(rowid) from emp b 
               where a.empno=b.empno);
```

Is `rowid` is unique for each row inserted? What is the use using `max(rowid)`?

Why can't I use the below query?

```
select distinct sal, distinct empno from emp;
```

Comment: The 2nd query will also work. The 1st one assumes, that rows are physically placed "sequentially" into the table. And it tries to select the newer one duplicate rows. This assumption is wrong. (Also the double `DISTINCT` is syntactically incorrect)

Comment: Suggested query returns one row per `empno` group with maximum rowID. Please explain what you need and what is the `SAL` field.

Comment: @Ivan the second query is wrong you can use DISTINCT only once after SELECT (also in COUNT(DISTINCT) but it isn't matter of this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ROWID is unique.

MAX (ROWID) is used when more than one row found (duplciate) for a condition, then the latest (last record after sort) is recorded here.

> First Query is to select all rows from table based on a distinct value
> of a column.
>
> Second Query is to select a column with its own
> distinctness.

Both queries will give you distinct. But wait `select distinct sal, distinct empno from emp;` is wrong, it should be `select distinct sal, empno from emp;`

Consider the following

```
--
-- DATASET  (Table)
--

CREATE TABLE DATASET ( VAL1 CHAR ( 1 CHAR ),
                        VAL2 VARCHAR2 ( 10 CHAR ),
                        VAL3 NUMBER );

INSERT INTO
      DATASET ( VAL1, VAL2, VAL3 )
VALUES
      ( 'b', 'b-details', 2 );

INSERT INTO
      DATASET ( VAL1, VAL2, VAL3 )
VALUES
      ( 'a', 'a-details', 1 );

INSERT INTO
      DATASET ( VAL1, VAL2, VAL3 )
VALUES
      ( 'c', 'c-details', 3 );

INSERT INTO
      DATASET ( VAL1, VAL2, VAL3 )
VALUES
      ( 'a', 'dup', 4 );

COMMIT;
```

Now your first query

```
SELECT
      *
FROM
      DATASET A
WHERE
      ROWID = (SELECT
                   MAX ( ROWID )
             FROM
                   DATASET B
             WHERE
                   A.VAL1 = B.VAL1);
                   

VAL1 VAL2             VAL3
---- ---------- ----------
b    b-details           2
a    as                  4
c    c-details           3

3 rows selected.
```

**PS:** I select all the columns (VAL1, VAL2, VAL3) with a distinct condition on one column (VAL1) so the duplicates are ordered by other columns and hence you see one row.

Now second query

```
SELECT DISTINCT VAl1 FROM DATASET;


VAL1
----
b   
a   
c   

3 rows selected.
```

**PS:** Here I select a distinct column (VAL1)

Answer (score 1):

1. rowid is unique for each row and the proposed request will get the last record inserted for each empno
2. Don't repeat DISTINCT, the following SQL Request will return all distinct couple of sal, empno

   ```
   select distinct sal, empno from emp;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by for getting distinct records.

select sal, empno from emp
group by Sal,empno;

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from emp a where rowid != (select max(rowid) from emp b where  a.empno=b.empno);
```

Comment: can any  one explain above?

Comment: Why are you suggesting a delete as an answer about how to do a select?

Answer (score 0):

Select eid, count(*) from employee group by eid having count(*)=1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).